# Unit test over Autofac Module to reach 100% code coverage

Tags: c#, unit-testing, code-coverage, autofac

We have a core library which make complex calculations and we consider it critical and we want to have a code coverage of 100% on that library. We now have 96% which is great, but we cant get the 100% because of this class:

```
public class IoCModule : Autofac.Module
{
    protected override void Load(Autofac.ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<SomeMathServiceA>().As<ISomeMathServiceA>();
        builder.RegisterType<SomeMathServiceB>().As<ISomeMathServiceB>(); 

        //... more registrations
    }
 }
```

I dont know how to test it, or if we really need to test it.

I have tried a unit test that take this module and create an `IContainer` and resolves every register dependency but some services access DB and config files which are very complex to mock in this context.

Done!!!!
[image]

Comment: 100% is in your head. It's better to test what's testable and deal with it than to test everything to get 100% and running some useless tests each time.

Comment: Take a look at the picture its not in my head.

Comment: I didn't said that you would never success, I questioned about the *real need* of reaching 100%. Congrats on getting it to the top :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Disclaimer: class-level unit test not deemed sensible

(by the author)

I guess by unit-testing you mean "class level unit tests" where the unit is a class. If you want to test the `IoCModule` you should employ component/library level testing where you test the whole library whether it's working correctly. This (should) include the `IoCModule` - and all the other stuff in the library. It's usually not feasible to reach 100% branch coverage using tests on this level, but the combination of tests on this level + class level unit tests make for a very good test reliability.
I'd also say it's better to reach 80% combined coverage than to only have class-level unit tests. While every class itself can work exactly according to the test, the whole may not work as intended. That's why you should perform component-level tests.

### How to verify whether a type is registered:

Now if you're still adamant about performing the tests, look no further, you can do it like that:

```
public class MyModuleTest
{
    private IContainer container;

    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void TestFixtureSetUp()
    {
        var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();

        // register module to test
        containerBuilder.RegisterModule<MyModule>(); 

        // don't start startable components - 
        // we don't need them to start for the unit test
        this.container = containerBuilder.Build(
            ContainerBuildOptions.IgnoreStartableComponents);
    }

    [TestCaseSource(typeof(TypesExpectedToBeRegisteredTestCaseSource))]
    public void ShouldHaveRegistered(Type type)
    {
        this.container.IsRegistered(type).Should().BeTrue();
    }

    [TestFixtureTearDown]
    public void TestFixtureTearDown()
    {
        this.container.Dispose();
    }

    private class TypesExpectedToBeRegisteredTestCaseSource : IEnumerable<object[]>
    {
        private IEnumerable<Type> Types()
        {
            // whatever types you're registering..
            yield return typeof(string);
            yield return typeof(int);
            yield return typeof(float);
        }

        public IEnumerator<object[]> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this.Types()
                .Select(type => new object[] { type })
                .GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
}
```

This gives test output like:
[image]

so each type is reported separately.

### Wow that was easy - so what's the problem again?

Now in the above example you can see that the test for `single` (=`float`) is passing. Now look at the module:

```
public class MyModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<float>();
    }
}
```

when we actually try to resolve `float` by:

```
container.Resolve<float>();
```

this is what happens:

> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException : No constructors on type 'System.Single' can be found with the constructor finder 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder'.

Of course we could just adapt the test to perform the `Resolve(Type t)` instead of using `IsRegistered(Type t)` - however there's plenty of other ways to make the test pass - but the implementation fail. For example:

- binding a type to use `builder.RegisterInstance<IFoo>(null)`
- changing lifetime/scopes so it doesn't work properly anymore.

Comment: Hi battery thank you for your anwser, I will use a combination of both.

Answer (score 6):

I finally found a way to test it. The autofac Module has a method Configure that register the components. This is how I did it:

```
public class CheckRegistrations
{
    [Test]
    public void Should_Have_Register_Types()
    {
        //Arrange
        var typesToCheck = new List<Type>
        {
            typeof (ISomeMathServiceA),
            typeof (ISomeMathServiceB)
        };

        //Act
        var typesRegistered = this.GetTypesRegisteredInModule(new IoCModule());

        //Arrange
        Assert.AreEqual(typesToCheck.Count, typesRegistered.Count());

        foreach (var typeToCheck in typesToCheck)
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(typesRegistered.Any(x => x == typeToCheck), typeToCheck.Name + " was not found in module");
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<Type> GetTypesRegisteredInModule(Module module)
    {
        IComponentRegistry componentRegistry = new ComponentRegistry();

        module.Configure(componentRegistry);

        var typesRegistered =
            componentRegistry.Registrations.SelectMany(x => x.Services)
                .Cast<TypedService>()
                .Select(x => x.ServiceType);

        return typesRegistered;
    }
}
```

Comment: i've extended my answer to show a) a nicer way to perform the test (test is performed per type - which means you'll see a list of all types passing / failing the test) b) why it's not a good idea to implement a test like this.

Comment: Could you create and post some end to end sample in github. it really helps. I am also looking for similar solution